# How to check or get the success of $state.go() in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, user-interface

We have one requirement in which `$state.go()` opens an HTML page with a dynamic table. Once this `$state.go` creates/loads the `<table>` tag then I have to set the values in the cells of this table. But as `$state.go` uses promise in back-end. So when the method calling this `$state.go` is called doesn't set the values for the first time. But start it from the next time.

The scenario is:

```
$scope.myfunction:function() {
  $state.go('xyz');
  setValues() //should be called once the previous line is completed
}
```

I have tried:

```
$rootscope.$on $stateChangeSuccess event //it is not triggered and there is no value inside toState
$state.go().then //which makes my code execute from the second time.
```

and lot more things.

Please help me out.

Comment: If it returns promise, then you should use `then`. `promise.then(function(data){})`

Comment: I have tried then as mentioned in I have tried section which makes it executes from second time.

Comment: So you want to transition the user to the new state `xyz` that loads a table. Within that new state `xyz` you want to populate the cells using the `setValues()` method? And do you have a controller for `xyz` state?

Comment: Yes thats true, except there is no explicit controller for xyz state its written within anotehr controller.

Comment: Create a controller per state it makes it easier to handle these things and keeps controllers small see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32864154/1230663) below

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need to populate the cells in the table after the user has transitioned to `xyz` state.

#### Adapting current setup

You should structure your project so that you have a controller per view. Using ui-router you can then pass whatever values that need to be populated in the table as params to the controller for state `xyz`. So it's something like this:

```
// allow params in xyz state config
$stateProvider
.state('xyz', {
    controller: 'XyzController',
    controllerAs: 'vm', // only necessary if you use controllerAs,
    params: {
        cellValue1: null, // this will get populated when the data gets passed by the other state's controller
        cellValue2: null
    },
    templateUrl: 'someTemplateUrl',
    url: 'someUrl'
});

// controller for starting state let's call it 'abc'
$scope.myfunction: function() {
    $state.go('xyz' {
        cellValue1: 'someCellValue1',
        cellValue2: 'someCellValue2'
    });
}

// controller for xyz
function XyzController() {
    setValues(); // will be called on controller load
}
```

#### A better solution

A better alternative for what you want to do is to use [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve). It makes more sense to do this from a technical design perspective and will prevent the rest of the page loading before the cells get populated on slower connections.

So within the route config for `xyz` state add the resolve property and the `setValues()` method:

```
$stateProvider
.state('xyz', {
    controller: 'XyzController',
    controllerAs: 'vm', // only necessary if you use controllerAs,
    resolve: {
        setValues: setValues()
    }
    templateUrl: 'someTemplateUrl',
    url: 'someUrl'
});

// inject into xyz controller
function XyzController(setValues) {
        cellValue1 = setValues.cellValue1; 
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Actually this state is called in 2 different scenarios, how can I put a check for separating both cases?

Comment: Do you mean that there are two states that call `$state.go('xyz')`?

Comment: I want that the table created by state.go should be done and then the setvalue should work. Will that work

Comment: But if you've already transitioned your user to `xyz` where they can see the table why do you want to call setvalue after that? If it's to populate the table, this is why i recommend having a separate controller for each state.

Comment: Once the controller has called `$state.go` the user transitions to `xyz` and the controller for `xyz` loads which includes resolving the method to populate the table.

Comment: If you have another controller that will call `$state.go('xyz')` do you still want the table in `xyz` to be populated?

Comment: Ok, let me go a bit deeper and explain a bit more of my scenario. In my project user creates this table in html and saves it on server. The same controller is used to update the table previously saved on server.so 1st scenario is create and 2nd is to update. In update the server values are in form of json which I need to set in the table so that if user has left some cells empty than he can update them. So in case of update it should populate in all cases.

Comment: So once the user has created the table they are transitioned to `xyz` that shows them the created table? And when they update the table they also get transitioned to `xyz` to view the updated table? If this is the case then the solution i've put will work - what's going on in your `setvalues()` method? That's the important part.

Comment: 1. The xyz has the table. Inwhich user has given some inputs and saved the table into server.
2. When in future user wants to update this table then he will be moved to xyz to display the last saved table with content. This content is set in the xyz table using setValue()
3. The value set works but on second time when user clicks it to edit. not the first time. I think this is due to async promise that executes internally for state.go()

Comment: Then you want to set the value first, wait for the request to complete then call state.go. Or that could be done in the function passed to `resolve`.

Comment: The logical flow to me would be 1. User clicks create table 2. Save table in database 3. Call `$state.go('xyz')` 4. Before controller for `xyz` loads call resolve function to retrieve newly created table and values

Comment: I want to correct your 4th point. The state.go should complete then only I will be able to retrieve the table created in this xyz and set the values. Therefore I want to create a check which set values once state.go is complete

Comment: But if the values are stored on the server before calling state.go() then you can get the values after calling state.go() and populate the page - you have 2 choices for doing this - call setvalues when the controller loads (see my point about slow connections) or use resolve.

Comment: Yes I am calling it after state.go() but it does not work for the first time and works from second time. I think that it is due to the internal call of promise in state.go() and resolve is giving me injector error

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other - i am saying that you should not be calling setvalues() in the same controller that you call stage.go(). Did you follow the documentation for resolve? You have to inject it into the `xyz` controller after declaring the function in the route config.

Answer (score 0):

UI-Router [state.go() return a promise](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state), so you could do something like:

```
$scope.myfunction:function() {
  $state.go('xyz')
     .then(function(){
       setValues(); //will be executed after $state.go() succeeds
     });
}
```